# Unable to set proxy to "subscription-manager repos --list" -command

Tags: linux, linux-networking, rhel6, rpm

I have RHEL6 system that is registered to rhn via subscription-manager. I'am trying to install package java-1.6.0-sun-devel which is in rhel-6-server-optional-rpms repository, According to this [Redhat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1.0/html/Subscription_Management_Guide/entitlements-and-yum.html). My system is behind proxy, so I need to enter command: "subscription-manager repos --list --proxy=myproxy.com:666" but this gives an error: "no such option --proxy". Subscription-manager's man-page does include --proxy as common option and I have used it to register this machine. Can you guys tell what's wrong?

/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log reports timed out connection.

Thank's from all the help!

edit 1. Some typos..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the other method of configuring a proxy server for Subscription Manager. This will also make the configuration persistent so that you won't have to specify it every time.

```
subscription-manager config --server.proxy_hostname=proxyserver.example.com --server.proxy_port=8080
```

See [Red Hat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1.0/html/Subscription_Management_Guide/rhsm-http-proxy.html) (not the page you quoted!) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Check the proxy settings for `subscription-manager` in this below file:

> /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf

Set the correct value for `proxy_hostname` and `proxy_port`. If needed fill out the `proxy_user` and `proxy_password` lines as well.